# Попап(модальное окно) JS

Tags: javascript

Не открывается модальное окно при нажатии на кнопку. Переписывал, менял кнопку на ссылку и все равно не открывается. Помогите пожалуйста.

```js
const modalLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-link');
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const lockPadding = document.querySelectorAll('.lock-padding');

let unlock = true;

const timeout = 800;

if (modalLinks.length > 0) {
  for (let index = 0; index < modalLinks.length; index++) {
    const modalLink = modalLinks[index];
    modalLink.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      const modalName = modalLink.getAttribute('href').replace('#', '');
      const curentModal = document.getElementById(modalName);
      modalOpen(curentModal);
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }
}

const modalCloseIcon = document.querySelectorAll('.close-modal');
if (modalCloseIcon.length > 0) {
  for (let index = 0; index < modalCloseIcon.length; index++) {
    const el = modalCloseIcon[index];
    el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      modalClose(el.closest('.modal'));
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }
}

function modalOpen(curentModal) {
  if (curentModal && unlock) {
    const modalActive = document.querySelector('.modal.open');
    if (modalActive) {
      modalClose(modalActive, false);
    } else {
      bodyLock();
    }
    curentModal.classList.add('open');
    curentModal.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      if (!e.target.closest('.modal-content')) {
        modalClose(e.target.closest('.modal'));
      }
    });
  }
}

function modalClose(modalActive, doUnlock = true) {
  if (unlock) {
    modalActive.classList.remove('open');
    if (doUnlock) {
      bodyUnlock();
    }
  }
}

function bodyLock() {
  const lockPaddingValue = window.innerWidth - document.querySelector('.wrapper-medium').offsetWidth + "px";

  if (lockPadding.length > 0) {
    for (let index = 0; index < lockPadding.length; index++) {
      const el = lockPadding[index];
      el.style.paddingRight = lockPaddingValue;
    }
  }
  body.style.paddingRight = lockPaddingValue;
  body.classList.add('lock');

  unlock = false;
  setTimeout(function () {
    unlock = true;
  }, timeout);
}

function bodyUnlock() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (lockPadding.length > 0) {
      for (let index = 0; index < lockPadding.length; index++) {
        const el = lockPadding[index];
        el.style.paddingRight = "0px";
      }
    }
    body.style.paddingRight = "0px";
    body.classList.remove('lock');
  }, timeout);

  unlock = false;
  setTimeout(function () {
    unlock = true;
  }, timeout);
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.which === 27) {
        const modalActive = document.querySelector('.modal.open');
    modalClose(modalActive);   
 }
});
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #13171d;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
  z-index: 101;
}

.modal.open {
  opacity: 0.9;
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal.open .modal-content {
  transform: perspective(500px) translate(0px, 0%) rotateX(0deg);
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.modal-body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 30px;
  transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: perspective(500px) translate(0px, -100%) rotate(45deg);
}

.modal-title {
  margin: 50px 87px 40px 88px;
  max-width: 325px;
  max-height: 447px;
  font-family: "Bebas Neue";
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #13171d;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  color: #13171d;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="button btn-main-action modal-link">Бесплатная консультация</button> 

<div id="modal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <a href="#" class="modal-close close-modal">X</a>
            <h3 class="modal-title">
                Оставьте заявку на <span>бесплатную</span> консультацию
            </h3>
            <form class="form modal-form">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="input modal-input" placeholder="Имя">
                <input type="tel" name="mail" class="input modal-input" placeholder="Телефон">
                <div class="modal-buttons">
                    <button type="submit" class="button modal-button">
                        Получить консультацию
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: К сожаленью у вас в вопросе не хватает некоторых `html` объектов, например с классом `lock-padding`, `close-modal` и т.д. Пожалуйста отредактируйте вопрос)

Comment: Добавил! Спасибо за вашу внимательность!

Comment: В данном JS lock-padding добавляется к header - так как он фиксированный и при открытии и закрытии чтобы контент под модальным окном не сдвигался из за скролла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть ошибки с классами...
Так же мне не понятно использование .querySelector**All** возможно это был корень зла. зачем эта коллекция узлов когда такая кнопка одна и класс соответствующий есть.
Некоторые элементы объявленные в js нет в куске кода HTML. 
 Переписал это участок: modalLink.addEventListener

```js
const modalLink = document.querySelector('.modal-link');
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const lockPadding = document.querySelectorAll('.lock-padding');
let unlock = true;
const timeout = 800;

modalLink.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  let modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
  modalOpen(modal);
  e.preventDefault();
});
const modalCloseIcon = document.querySelector('.close-modal');
const el = modalCloseIcon;
el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  modalClose(el.closest('.modal'));
  e.preventDefault();
});

function modalOpen(curentModal) {
  if (curentModal && unlock) {
    const modalActive = document.querySelector('.modal');
    if (modalActive) {
      modalClose(modalActive, false);
    } else {
      bodyLock();
    }
    curentModal.classList.add('open');
    curentModal.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      if (!e.target.closest('.modal-content')) {
        modalClose(e.target.closest('.modal'));
      }
    });
  }
}

function modalClose(modalActive, doUnlock = true) {
  if (unlock) {
    modalActive.classList.remove('open');
    if (doUnlock) {
      bodyUnlock();
    }
  }
}

function bodyLock() {
  const lockPaddingValue =
    window.innerWidth -
    document.querySelector('.wrapper-medium').offsetWidth +
    'px';

  if (lockPadding.length > 0) {
    for (let index = 0; index < lockPadding.length; index++) {
      const el = lockPadding[index];
      el.style.paddingRight = lockPaddingValue;
    }
  }
  body.style.paddingRight = lockPaddingValue;
  body.classList.add('lock');

  unlock = false;
  setTimeout(function () {
    unlock = true;
  }, timeout);
}

function bodyUnlock() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (lockPadding.length > 0) {
      for (let index = 0; index < lockPadding.length; index++) {
        const el = lockPadding[index];
        el.style.paddingRight = '0px';
      }
    }
    body.style.paddingRight = '0px';
    body.classList.remove('lock');
  }, timeout);

  unlock = false;
  setTimeout(function () {
    unlock = true;
  }, timeout);
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  if (e.which === 27) {
    const modalActive = document.querySelector('.modal.open');
    modalClose(modalActive);
  }
});
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #13171d;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
  z-index: 101;
}

.modal.open {
  opacity: 0.9;
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal.open .modal-content {
  transform: perspective(500px) translate(0px, 0%) rotateX(0deg);
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.modal-body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 30px;
  transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: perspective(500px) translate(0px, -100%) rotate(45deg);
}

.modal-title {
  margin: 50px 87px 40px 88px;
  max-width: 325px;
  max-height: 447px;
  font-family: "Bebas Neue";
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #13171d;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  color: #13171d;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="button btn-main-action modal-link">Бесплатная консультация</button> 

<div id="modal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <a href="#" class="modal-close close-modal">X</a>
            <h3 class="modal-title">
                Оставьте заявку на <span>бесплатную</span> консультацию
            </h3>
            <form class="form modal-form">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="input modal-input" placeholder="Имя">
                <input type="tel" name="mail" class="input modal-input" placeholder="Телефон">
                <div class="modal-buttons">
                    <button type="submit" class="button modal-button">
                        Получить консультацию
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам просто огромнейшее! На самом деле попап будет еще в нескольких местах, просто я сюда прикрепил одну кнопку, для примера!

Comment: Да не за что.)))

Comment: Сейчас перенес это в JS и все равно не открывается а в консоль выдаёт вот это -  Uncaught TypeError: modalLink.addEventListener is not a function
    at modal-win.js:7:11

Comment: Посмотри классы в HTML, все хорошенько сверь, а лучше вставь кусок html с этого примера.   Смотри внимательно имена  переменных и дальнейшее их использование в коде, что бы не было опечаток, ну и правильно обращайся по классу в JS. Как правило ошибка в элементарных моментах.

Comment: Все скопировал от и до результат такой же ругается именно на строку с addEventListener, в codopen все работает. я хз почему так

Comment: Всё разобрался. так подключение js было в header - забыл добавить defer :D

Comment: )))ошибка всегда там где меньше всего ее ждешь